# Can we get access to key-usage metrics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Will developers ever get a chance to see how often their app key is being used?

Or how many unique IPs are used the key?

Or any other random metrics that might be interesting?

Answer (score 3):

Should the access to these statistics be limited to the owner of the API key for privacy reasons?

Comment: Probably yes... or at least yes for the IP stats.